# Erro instalação Glassfish

Tags: glassfish

Bom dia time do SOF!

Podem me ajudar na instalação que estou fazendo do Glassfish4?
É para um curso de JSF que estou fazendo.

Quando tento criar um server environment ele da esse erro:
[image: Erro solicitando uma JRE]

Quando mudo para a JRE instalada ele da esse outro erro pedindo a JDK:
[image: Erro solicitando uma JDK]

E nunca saio disso.

Alguém manja uma solução?

Este é o eclipse Junos.

Antes eu usava o Tomcat que nunca reclamou de nada, mas era no eclipse Mars.
Não sei se ajuda em algo, mas só informando.

Obrigado a todos desde já.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está apontando para um JRE, não um JDK. Clique em "Installed JRE Preferences" ali em cima na tela para adicionar a referência a um JDK instalado no seu computador, para você usar na criação do servidor GlassFish.

Se você não tiver um JDK instalado, baixe no site da Oracle e faça a instalação.

Você também deve selecionar um Runtime name com a versão GlassFish 4.1, compatível com a versão encontrada no diretório apontado.